# Prove $S\subseteq R$, $\forall a,b \in R : a \lt b$ : $S \cap (a,b)$ is at most countable, then S is at most countable.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: $S\subseteq R$,    $\forall a,b \in R : a \lt b$ : $S \cap (a,b)$ is at most countable, then S is at most countable.

if $S \cap (a,b)$ is at most countable then S is at most countable.

How do i prove that a set is "at most" countable?

I would really appreciate some explaination about how to prove it.

Comment: S doesnt have to be finite, it is just a subset of the Rational numbers (R)

Comment: @Amir $S$ can be finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: union of countably many at most countable sets is at most countable. Also, $$S=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(S\cap(-n,n)\right)$$

Comment: How does that help me?

Comment: @YvesHalimi I have added a further hint. You should be able to finish from here.

Comment: I think i got it. So the union of all the at-most-coutable intersections between S and (a,b)  is also countable, but it is also covers  all S, because if any x is in the intersection, then it is in S and in (a,b), therefore we get S. then S is at most countable?

Comment: I wanna make sure i understand it thoroughly, because i might be asked something similar in the test at the end of the semester.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.